# Where to download SunPKCS11Provider

Tags: jce, jsse

I'm trying to access smardCard folowing this [article](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3587361/Java-Applet-for-Signing-with-a-Smart-Card.htm) but I have no idea where to find jar with SunPKCS11Provider. In Oracle docs they say it is standard since 1.5. Here is my block where compiler is complaining it can't find SunPKCS11:

```
String configName = "d:\\dev\\ws\\pkiTest\\pkcs11.cfg";
Provider p = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(configName);
Security.addProvider(p);
```

Comment: OK, the problem is as oracle java 6 doc says "It is also supported on 32-bit Windows (x86) but not currently on 64-bit Windows platforms due to the lack of suitable PKCS#11 libraries.".

Answer (score 3):

64 bit windows support should become available in next few months. it's being backported to a jdk 6 update.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6931562

Comment: this link points to a bug related to SunMSCAPI, not SunPKCS11.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't available for download until Java 8 (for 64 bit):
"The class SunPKCS11 is not available even in JDK/JRE 7 for WIndows 64 bit." (Duplicate bug description)  http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6880559

It was introduced in Java 5 (32 bit), and is included in Oracle's JDK downloads since then. It was not backported to the 64 bit versions after introduced in Java 8 (64 bit).

I think the other answer is referring to a different provider (SunMSCAPI).

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Finally have reputation to respond in comments. ^^     I hope my edit was sufficient.